# Python Regex ignore specific string to find next example

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have the following code that runs through and strips the data in the current column and creates a secondary column with just the code in parentheses and this works wonderfully in example 2 & 3.  However in example one, i am seeing situations where the date is being picked up because it is also in parentheses.  Is there a way to rework the code to ignore anything within the parenthesis that has a datestamp and continue to look for something else within that record, for example in scenario 1, scan record one, ignore(2018-03) and select (256).  The datasets we worth with have 3,4,5 and other various of record codes, but this date type is unique and can be removed.

Code:

```
df1['Doc ID'] = df['Folder Path'].str.extract('.*\((.*)\).*',expand=True)
```

Data Table:

```
current column                                                new column
1  /reports/support + admin. (256)/ Global (2018-03)        (2018-03)
2  /reports/limit/sector(139)/2017                               (139)
3  /reports/sector/region(147,189 and 132)/2018                  (147,189 and 132)
```

Comment: Just match the first parentheses, `r'\(([^()]*)\)'`

Comment: The `.*` cause the engine to go straight to the end, then look backwards one char at a time. To find the _first_ non-empty, parenthesized without the date would be something like `\((?!date_format)([^()]+)\)`

Comment: sln, thanks for your help.  I added your code to my script, and it fixes one issue, but there is a second issue now.  Is there a way to modify the below code to also ignore the string (Data Only)?  When running the script, this string often times shows up first before the record id: df1['Doc ID'] = df['Folder Path'].str.extract('.*\((?!date_format)([^()]+)\)',expand=True) and do you know of a good place where i can learn more about regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
df['Folder Path'].str.extract(r'\((?!\d{4}-\d{2}\)|Data Only\))([^()]*)\)',expand=True)
```

The regex matches

- `\(` - an open parenthesis
- `(?!\d{4}-\d{2}\)|Data Only\))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is

  - `\d{4}-\d{2}\)` - 4 digits, hyphen, 2 hyphens, `)`
  - `|` - or
  - `Data Only\)` - `Data Only)` substrinbg
- `([^()]*)` - Group 1: any 0 or more chars other than open/close parentheses
- `\)` - a close parenthesis

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CRWLEt/1).